# MYSQL - Calculating Friday as "end of week" is returning "null" when "start of week" is in April and "end of week" is May, how do I fix this?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to get the last working day of the week (Friday) e.g. 2019-04-30 should give me 2019-05-04, but instead returns Null. How would I solve this? My existing code is below.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE FUNCTION FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK(day DATE)
RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN SUBDATE(day, WEEKDAY(day));
END;;
DELIMITER ;


SELECT ID, parent_id, created_by_id, old_value, new_value, field, date, date(FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK(date)+4) AS end_of_week_fri
FROM new_history_team_member;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use date_Add

```
set @date = '2019-04-30';

select f(@date),date_add(F(@date), interval 4 day);

+------------+------------------------------------+
| f(@date)   | date_add(F(@date), interval 4 day) |
+------------+------------------------------------+
| 2019-04-29 | 2019-05-03                         |
+------------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.024 sec)
```

PS I renamed your function to F so as not to clutter up my db but otherwise unchanged